# Neutral translation of "suburb"

Tags: traduction, terminologie, société

In French, the common translation for English *suburb* seems to be [*banlieue*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/suburb). Unfortunately, however, this term has quite a lot of (negative) pragmatic baggage at least in France (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banlieue#mw-content-text))<sup>†</sup>; Is there no way of referring to a "suburb" in a truly neutral manner, without resorting to the use of qualifiers or euphemisms?

---

<sup>†</sup>I'm not sure about the situation in e.g. Belgium or Switzerland, but I've heard that term is not "loaded" in this manner in Quebecois French.

Comment: Maybe "périphérie [de la ville]"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In late 20th/21st centuries *banlieue* used without a qualifier refers to what would be called "[Inner city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_city)" in the US. *[Faubourg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faubourg)* is the neutral one word translation of "suburb" but the word *banlieue* will mostly be used with a qualifier to endorse a different connotation e.g. *une banlieue résidentielle* would correspond to a "[suburb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suburb#North_America)" in some English speaking countries. If used without a qualifier it can still be understood with its original geographical meaning if context is clear. If someone tells you :

> J'habite une belle maison en banlieue.

Then there's no doubt as to what sort of area they live in. They would not use the phrase if they lived in a ZUP (more or less the equivalent of the US "housing projects").

In a different context when you see newspaper titles such as:

> [Les jeunes de banlieue, ces « étrangers de l'intérieur assignés à résidence »](http://bibliobs.nouvelobs.com/actualites/20130313.OBS1712/les-jeunes-de-banlieue-ces-etrangers-de-l-interieur-assignes-a-residence.html)
>
> [Portrait noir de la crise économique en banlieue](http://www.lemonde.fr/banlieues/article/2016/05/03/dans-les-quartiers-prioritaires-le-chomage-affecte-de-plus-en-plus-fortement-diplomes-et-non-immigres_4912791_1653530.html)

we know straight away (and especially when referring to youth) the word *banlieue* is in this context associated with minorities, poverty, violence, drugs, etc.

Comment: +1 for *faubourg*, but if “inner city” has come to mean “banlieue,” where does “urbain/e” fit in? It’s curious how the negative baggage associated with *suburbs/suburban/suburbia* in English (i.e., boring/provincial) is not present in *banlieue.* Does *faubourg* capture this negative (boring/provincial) sense of *suburbia*? Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that you will never hear Faubourg in Québécois French. You will not be understood.

Comment: @PapaPoule Not a geographical but sociological issue. OP was mentioning the negative baggage of *banlieue* in France. That's because when you speak of * les jeunes de banlieue* (it's not an opinion, just google the phrase and read the press) it is associated with minorities, poverty, violence, drugs, delinquency, ...  [A sociology paper about what the term carries](http://www.persee.fr/doc/colan_0336-1500_1997_num_113_1_2789). Correct me if I'm wrong, but seen through the press (I've never lived in the US) it's the same with [US inner cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_city).

Comment: @PapaPoule *Faubourg* does not carry any negative sense, it's not much used nowadays anyway, people still prefer *banlieue* + qualifier. I can't find a better word than *banlieue résidentielle* to fit suburbia.

Comment: Does this mean that e.g. *j'habite dans une banlieue (résidentielle) de Paris* conjures no negative images in the mind of the reader/hearer, even in an indirect way such as in e.g. *I live in a nice part of the inner city* (the "nice part" used as a qualifier doesn't "prevent" the negative connotations but rather dismisses them after the fact)?

Comment: @errantlinguist  absolutely. I expect that *nice part of the inner city* would correspond to *banlieue pavillonaire*, which is a different concept from *banlieue résidentielle*.  *Banlieue pavillonaire* can still be associated with lower income (renting vs ownership, lower skilled jobs...).

Comment: @Laure, so what I take from this is that *banlieue* can in fact be used in a neutral manner (without conjuring any negative images even indirectly), but it is highly context-dependent --- does this sound right?

Interestingly, in contrast, *inner city* pretty much always comes with this sociological baggage, i.e. it is *not* context-dependent.

Comment: @errantlinguist. I think you've summed it up nicely with "highly context-dependent". I've expanded my answer to make it more clear. Should I  add some more, like the example about "*jeunes de banlieue*" I was giving PapaPoule?

Comment: @Laure, perhaps for posterity the "*jeunes de banlieue*" would be nice, but, at least for my purposes, this is a great answer and so I'm accepting it.

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur. It is also the same in mainland France. Faubourg is a good neutral translation for suburbs, but far out of date.
Banlieue has not always a negative baggage, that depends on which one you are talking about (some can be wealthier than the main city). You may still have to manage with banlieue and its context or some qualifiers.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to translate "suburb" in a more neutral way than *banlieue*.

In addition to *périphérie* already suggested by Jylo's comment, here are two other that come to mind, despite being euphemisms which you rule out in your question:

- autour de
- dans les environs de

e.g.:

> Je cherche à louer une maison dans les environs de Lyon.

Comment: All those three terms only deal with the geographical issue, not the sociological issue. In France *les banlieues* (unqualified) are in the *périphérie/ environs...* for which you'd use the word "outskirts" in English.  Besides *dans les environs* and *autour* cover a larger geographical area than *banlieue* and *périphérie*, the latter imply  continuity with the city, *environs*  doesn't.

Comment: @Laure I precisely suggested these terms because they do not convey any sociological baggage, which is how I understand the main part of the OP question. Whether they perfectly match "suburb" definition might not be an issue. I agree *autour de* and *les environs de* are slightly wider and less precise than *banlieue* and *périphérie*, but even the latter are somewhat fuzzy. There is no continuity with the city when banlieue is taken as its *grande banlieue* acception.

Comment: While these terms do "work", are they not euphemisms?-- *périphérie de la ville* literally means "outskirts of the city", which may mean in some cornfields depending on the city (since not all cities have satellite towns/suburbs around them). In other words, you're avoiding saying where you really live (*dans la banlieue*) even though everyone knows that's what you mean through context (e.g. since there are no cornfields surrounding Paris proper-- only suburbs)

Comment: Precisely, I'm avoiding to say the *banlieue* because you asked for a neutral term which *banlieue* is not. In any case, it is hard to expect a single French word to exactly match an English one, especially whithout knowing in what context that word will be used and given the fact it covers many different realities, including in the English speaking countries. One inhabitant of Versailles is unlikely to state he is living in the *banlieue* of Paris and to some extents, some French suburbs correspond to US inner cities.